# alpha shapes for polygonal boundary detection - for point cloud data

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

i am trying to implement alpha shape algorithm but the theories is quite hard to undestand. so, if any one know (or have) pseudo codes to implement alpha shape (2d) algorithm please post us.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_2/Chapter_main.html) has code for 2d alpha shapes.

Comment: See also [hull - convex hulls, Delaunay triangulations, alpha shapes](http://www.netlib.org/voronoi/hull.html)